# How to make two gradients with different gradientUnits looks the same in recharts line chart?

Tags: javascript, svg, recharts

Description:
I have a need to apply gradient for chart lines and since straight lines with gradient is not displayed using `objectBoundingBox`( see [SVG Line with Gradient Stroke Won't Display if vertical or horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638169/svg-line-with-gradient-stroke-wont-display-if-vertical-or-horizontal/21639059#21639059) - note that I can not use second suggestion from that thread and add some small number to last point since it can cause recharts related bugs ) - `userSpaceOnUse` was used, but it is applied not as I expected:

https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-wildflower-y7d7gv?file=/src/App.tsx

Here we have two lines with two gradients applied to them - the only difference between those are `gradientUnits`. There are 6 points( 5 segments ) and `offset` is equal to 80%. I assume that gradient transition would happen at 4th point(`Page E`) and it works exactly like this with `objectBoundingBox`, but not with `userSpaceOnUse` gradient. The gradient transition point is moved and this extra offset is dynamic, so for 80% transition happens too late, for 20% it happens too early.

What I've tried:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50624704/8738402 -tried to pick correct scaling for my case, but couldn't figure out what is the formula here( even so I picked scaling manually for each point - see no correlation )
- [Algorithm to convert userSpaceOnUse coordinates to objectBoundingBox coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431621/algorithm-to-convert-userspaceonuse-coordinates-to-objectboundingbox-coordinates) - here described a way to convert coordinates from one units to another, but I'm a little bit confused about how can it be applied to my case(must I move from percentage to precise coorditates?)

Would appreciate any suggestions here about how it can be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what helped me was moving from percentage to number coordinates. The formula is:

```
x1: containerWidth - actual path width - right margin
x2: containerWidth - rightMargin;
```

Code sample which was referenced in question was updated using that logic.